# YouTrack REST API - Create new priority

Tags: c#, youtrack

I I’m looking for a way to create a new priority value with the REST API.
In the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/PUT-Value.html) I found the following endpoint:

```
/rest/admin/customfield/bundle/{bundleName}/{fieldValue}?{description}&{colorIndex}
```

Calling this endpoint returns a **415** status code with the content:

```
{"value":"Unsupported Media Type"}
```

Here is my code:

```
var connection = YouTrackConnectionFactory.GetConnection();
var client = await connection.GetAuthenticatedHttpClient();

var priorityValue = "SomeNewPrio";
var enumerationName = "Priorities";
var queryString = new Dictionary<String, String>
{
    { "bundleName", enumerationName },
    { "fieldValue", priorityValue },
    { "description", WebUtility.UrlEncode( "Automatically created priority" ) },
    { "colorIndex", "9" }
};

var response = await client.PutAsync( $"/rest/admin/customfield/bundle/{enumerationName}/{priorityValue}", new FormUrlEncodedContent( queryString ) );
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

Is there something wrong with my data or is there another endpoint I should be using?

Comment: I don't know youtrack, but usually a media type error is caused by a missing content-type header. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/YouTrack-REST-API-Reference.html. If `client` is a `HttpClient` derived class,  `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");`might work

Comment: `client` is a `HttpClient`. Setting the header makes no difference. Request to other endpoints work with the same instance.